# How to pass parameter to AppShell TabBar page?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.shell

I am developing a multi-platform app using Xamarin Forms, and I need to pass a parameter with the user informations from my LoginPage to my HarvestPage (it is an app for farmers, btw). I'm using MVVM architecture, but no MVVM framework.

So, the user performs authentication in `LoginPage` and then the app navigates to my `AppShell` where I have 4 bottom tabs.

In `LoginPage.xaml.cs` I navigate to the first tab of my ShellPage (this page does not need parameters):

```cs
private async void OnLoginClicked(LoginViewModel sender, Usuario args)
{
    Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell(args);
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//market");
}
```

Then in my `AppShell.xaml` page I declare the contents of my tabs:

```xml
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Title="Market" Icon="exchange.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MarketPage}" Route="market" />
    <ShellContent Title="Harvest" Icon="sugarcane.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HarvestPage}" Route="harvest" />
    ...
</TabBar>
```

And in `AppShell.xaml.cs` I configure the routes:

```cs
private Usuario _user;

public AppShell(Usuario user)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _user = user;

    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(HarvestPage), typeof(HarvestPage));
    Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MarketPage), typeof(MarketPage));
    ...
}
```

The user infos are sent to `AppShell.xaml.cs` but how do I pass the user parameter to my `HarvestPage`?

I can't use `GoToAsync` like it is suggested in other questions, because there is no button to navigate, the navigation from MarketPage to HarvestPage is through the bottom tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define as public:

```
public Usuario User;
```

and then access it from your `HarvestPage` using:

```
(Shell.Current as AppShell).User
```